# Output AoA is overwriting information in loop

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to cycle through an AoA of that contains various information on systems and their IP addresses.  I'm running commands successfully to get the information I need.  When I have the print statement in the loop, it gives me the correct information I am looking for.  However when I run create a CSV file afterwards it appears that only the last value of each type of system is saved and overwrites all previous ones.

```
foreach my $row(@data){
my @columns;
if((index($row->[0], 'Model_A') != -1)) != -1)){
   my @result = qx(echo y | command goes here);
    foreach my $i(@result){
            if($i =~ /Port ID:\s+(\d)/){
        $columns[2] = $1;
    } elsif($i =~ /IP ID:\s+\d+)/){
        $columns[3] = $1;
    } 
    elsif(index($i, 'Port Status') != -1){
        $columns[0] = $row->[0];
        $columns[1] = $row->[1];
        print "$columns[0] \t $columns[1] \t $columns[2] \t $columns[3] \n";
        push (@output, \@columns);
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Example output should be something like

- Model_A  System 1 0 address_0
     Model_A  System 1 1 address_1
     Model_A  System 1 2 address_2
     Model_A  System 1 3 address_3

But instead comes out as

- Model_A  System 1 3 address_3
     Model_A  System 1 3 address_3
     Model_A  System 1 3 address_3
     Model_A  System 1 3 address_3

But when in my print statement it is giving the correct values write before adding the columns to the output array.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the same array reference over and over, and saving the values to the hard coded indexes in that array, so only the last values are kept.

```
my @columns;
...
foreach my $i(@result){
    ...
    push (@output, \@columns);   # identical reference each iteration
```

This might work if you declared the `@columns` array inside the loop instead of outside it. That way, a new array would be created for each iteration, instead of the same one.

```
foreach my $i(@result){
    ...
    my @columns;
    ...
    push (@output, \@columns);   # new reference each iteration
```